# Convertir fechas al leer un dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Necesito leer un archivo con la forma

```
1234567890123|02/01/2020 01:00:37 PM|02/01/2020 01:01:06 PM
0987654321098|02/01/2020 01:02:21 PM|02/01/2020 01:03:26 PM
```

He definido los nombres de los campos, el separador, **y las clases como *texto***

```r
CAMPOS <- c(
  'folio', 'fecha_tramite', 'fecha_exitoso'
)
SEPARADOR <- "|"
CLASES <- c("character", "character", "character")
```

Creo mi *dataframe* con la siguiente orden

````r
ene <- read.table(
  "tramites.txt", 
  header = FALSE, 
  col.names = CAMPOS, 
  sep = SEPARADOR, 
  comment.char="", 
  colClasses = CLASES
)

Ahora, quiero convertir las fechas al formato adecuado _al momento de leer el archivo_, aplicando la siguiente función

```r
library(lubridate)
dmy_hms("02/01/2020 05:39:25 PM", tz="Mexico/General")
````

### Pregunta:

¿Cómo puedo aplicar la función `dmy_hms()` a las columnas adecuadas de mi archivo al momento de leerlo con `read.table()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En R existe una función llamada setAs que te permite crear tus propias definiciones de clases tomando el ejemplo que nos brindas se realizaría de la siguiente manera

```
library(lubridate)

 texto<-c("1234567890123|02/01/2020 01:00:37 PM|02/01/2020 01:01:06 PM
         0987654321098|02/01/2020 01:02:21 PM|02/01/2020 01:03:26 PM")

 con<-textConnection(texto)

 CAMPOS <- c("folio","fecha_tramite","fecha_exitoso")
 SEPARADOR <- "|"

 #creamos una clase llamada mifecha esto evita que nos salga un warning de que no 
 #existe
 setClass("mifecha")
 #Creamos la caracteristicas nuestra clase , es decir que tipo de clase acepta 
 # y cual la convierte
 setAs("character","mifecha",function(x) dmy_hms(from,tz="Mexico/General"))

 CLASES <- c("character", "mifecha", "mifecha")

 ene<-read.table(con,
       header=FALSE,
       col.names = CAMPOS,
       sep=SEPARADOR,
       comment.char = "",
       colClasses = CLASES)

 ene$fecha_tramite
 [1] "2020-01-02 13:00:37 CST" "2020-01-02 13:02:21 CST"
```